# Splitting of Training and Test set when the dataset could be updated

Tags: scikit-learn

I am following the code of the "Hands on Machine learning with Sci-kit learn and tensorflow 2nd edition" ([ipynb link](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb)). In the section on selection the training and test data sets, the author brings up the importance of writing the splitting function so that the test set will stay consistent over multiple runs, even if the data set is refreshed. The code is written so that an updated data set will still have the right percentage (`test ratio`) for splitting the test and training sets, but the new test set won't contain any instance that was previously in the training set. It does this by creating a number for the index value(`identifier/id_x`) and returning true if that number is between 0 and (`test ratio`) of the range of possible numbers that could be selected.

```
from zlib import crc32

def test_set_check(identifier, test_ratio):
    return crc32(np.int64(identifier)) & 0xffffffff < test_ratio * 2**32

def split_train_test_by_id(data, test_ratio, id_column):
    ids = data[id_column]
    in_test_set = ids.apply(lambda id_: test_set_check(id_, test_ratio))
    return data.loc[~in_test_set], data.loc[in_test_set]
```

This part makes sense, but what I don't understand is how to implement the same thing using the function `train_test_split` from `skilearn` is there something specific to do that if the whole data set is updated then the test set never includes a value that was already selected to be in the training set. Is this something that is already included if we include the `random_state` argument and make sure that the updated data set only adds rows to the existing data set and never deletes rows? Is that a realistic thing to require?

Is this a problem to worry about with cross validation as well?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about that rows from training set once will be part of testing set and will eventually effect the performance of classifier when using `test_train_split` I would suggest don't worry that won't happen. In order to keep training and testing consistent over multiple runs `random_state` can be used.